# Oracle to PostgreSQL query converter Possible?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql

I am thinking to write a converter that takes any oracle query and return Postgresql format of the query assuming table and columns are same.

what I do right now I do timely conversions so I have basic understanding about both and want some expert advice that is it easily possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible for *every* query. They each have syntax and functionality that the other does not -- for example, the MODEL clause in Oracle, or PostgreSQL's special form of "SELECT DISTINCT ON".

Mostly, Oracle has functionality that PostgreSQL doesn't: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm

Answer (score 2):

Try to use "commercial" version of PostgreSQL - EnterpriseDB. It has an compatibility layer for Oracle.

If you're about to write the "convector"  by your own: look at this github project: https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser. It's open-source parser for Oracle's SQL dialect. I have to warn you, even if you have AST for Oracle query it is still a lot of to do to convert AST into other SQL dialect. You will also need plenty of sample queries for testing. You can find some sample queries in this project's tests folder.

Also similar project was implemented for MySQL, but I can not find it's homepage now.

Comment: your answer is also helpful but I was looking for hurdles that can come in writing such converter.

Comment: ok if you're looking for hurdless: MODEL clause (as decribed above), analytic functions, query factoring (aka CTEs), set opertors like "INTERSECT", "MEMBER OF", PIVOT/UNPIVOT, XMLQUERY support. Various functions with crazy calling conventions. CUBE things like GROUP BY ROLLUP(). You can find samples for parser unit tests here: https://github.com/ibre5041/plsql-parser/tree/master/tests.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the solution is to make available in PostgreSQL the functions available in Oracle. You can have a look at http://orafce.projects.pgfoundry.org/

"The goal of this project is to implemente some functions from Oracle database. Some date functions (next_day, last_day, trunc, round, ...), string functions and some modules (DBMS_ALERT, DBMS_OUTPUT, UTL_FILE, DBMS_PIPE, ...) are implemented now. Funcionality was verified on Oracle 10g and module is useful for production work."